# Probability Theory: How to prove inequality $\mathbb{E}|X - m|^3 \leq \mathbb{E}|X|^3 (1 + \frac{m}{\sigma})^3$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Let's define $X$ - random variable with $F(x)$ distribution function.

Also, denote $m = \mathbb{E}X$ and $\sigma^2 = \mathbb{D}X$.

Suppose, that $m>0$.

How to prove this inequality in these conditions?

$\mathbb{E}|X - m|^3 \leq \mathbb{E}|X|^3 (1 + \frac{m}{\sigma})^3$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Did I think about using function $(\mathbb{E}|X|^u)^\frac{1}{u}$ for this. But after a while I can't prove $\sigma$ existence  in right part.

Comment: The meaning of "using function ... for this" escapes me. Could you explain?

Comment: I thought to use function $(E|X|^u)^{\frac{1}{u}}$ to prove this inequality, but I stuck at $\sigma$ existence in right part